# Getting normal text in unicode form in sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, unicode

I am using on sqlite database in my iOS project. I have got already prepared database where I am getting english text, Punjabi Text, Hindi text and english tranlation. I am using this code to fetch data from database:

```
    NSMutableArray *getData = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        getData = [[DBManager sharedDatabase]tableBani:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select *from TableBani"]];
        NSLog(@"getData..%@",getData);


but in result I am getting this from data base:

getData..(
        {
        EnglishText = "Ik\U201a\U00f1\U00b4oa\U2248\U00e2k\U0192\U00c5r sa\U00b7\U03c0\U00d8 n\U0192\U00c5m kar\U00b7\U03c0\U00d8\U0192\U00c5 purak\U00b7\U222b\U00f1 nirb\U00b7\U222b\U00f1a\U201a\U00f1\U00b4o nirvair ak\U0192\U00c5l m\U2248\U00b4ra\U00b7\U03c0\U00d8 aj\U2248\U00b4n\U0192\U00b4 saib\U00b7\U222b\U00f1a\U2248\U00e2 gur pars\U0192\U00c5\U00b7\U220f\U00e8.";
        EnglishTranslation = "One Universal Creator God. The Name Is Truth. Creative Being Personified. No Fear. No Hatred. Image Of The Undying, Beyond Birth, Self-Existent. By Guru's Grace ~";
        HindiText = "\U2021\U00a9\U00a5 \U2021\U00a7\U220f\U2021\U00a7\U00a7\U2021\U00a7\U00f8 \U2021\U00a7\U00ae\U2021\U00a7\U00e6\U2021\U00a7\U00c6\U2021\U2022\U00c5 \U2021\U00a7\U00ef\U2021\U00a7\U221e\U2021\U00a7\U00a7\U2021\U00a7\U00e6 \U2021\U00a7\U2122\U2021\U2022\U00c5\U2021\U00a7\U221e\U2021\U00a7\U00f1\U2021\U2022\U00c5 \U2021\U00a7\U00ae\U2021\U00a7\U00f8\U2021\U00a7\U221e\U2021\U00a7\U2260\U2021\U00a7\U00e2 \U2021\U00a7\U00ae\U2021\U00a7\U00f8\U2021\U00a7\U221e\U2021\U00a7\U00b5\U2021\U2022\U00e0\U2021\U00a7\U221e\U2021\U2022\U00c5 \U2021\U00a7\U00d6\U2021\U00a7\U00ef\U2021\U00a7\U00e6\U2021\U00a7\U2264 \U2021\U00a7\U00c6\U2021\U2022\U00c7\U2021\U00a7\U221e\U2021\U00a7\U00a7\U2021\U00a7\U00f8 \U2021\U00a7\U00d6\U2021\U00a7\U00fa\U2021\U2022\U00c7\U2021\U00a7\U00ae\U2021\U2022\U00c4 \U2021\U00a7\U220f\U2021\U2022\U00e0\U2021\U00a7\U2260\U2021\U00a7\U00c7 \U2021\U00a7\U00f3\U2021\U2022\U00c5\U2021\U00a7\U221e \U2021\U00a7\U2122\U2021\U2022\U00e7\U2021\U00a7\U221e\U2021\U00a7\U220f\U2021\U00a7\U00e6\U2021\U00a7\U00b6\U2021\U00a7\U00f8 \U2021\U2022\U2022";
        ID = 1;
        PunjabiText = "\U2021\U00a9\U00a5 \U2021\U00ae\U220f\U2021\U00ae\U00a7\U2021\U00ae\U00f8 \U2021\U00ae\U00ae\U2021\U00ae\U00e6\U2021\U00ae\U00c6\U2021\U00a9\U00c5 \U2021\U00ae\U00ef\U2021\U00ae\U221e\U2021\U00ae\U00a7\U2021\U00ae\U00e6 \U2021\U00ae\U2122\U2021\U00a9\U00c5\U2021\U00ae\U221e\U2021\U00ae\U00f1\U2021\U00a9\U00c5 \U2021\U00ae\U00ae\U2021\U00ae\U00f8\U2021\U00ae\U221e\U2021\U00ae\U2260\U2021\U00ae\U00e2 \U2021\U00ae\U00ae\U2021\U00ae\U00f8\U2021\U00ae\U221e\U2021\U00ae\U00b5\U2021\U00a9\U00e0\U2021\U00ae\U221e\U2021\U00a9\U00c5 \U2021\U00ae\U00d6\U2021\U00ae\U00ef\U2021\U00ae\U00e6\U2021\U00ae\U2264 \U2021\U00ae\U00c6\U2021\U00a9\U00c7\U2021\U00ae\U221e\U2021\U00ae\U00a7\U2021\U00ae\U00f8 \U2021\U00ae\U00d6\U2021\U00ae\U00fa\U2021\U00a9\U00c7\U2021\U00ae\U00ae\U2021\U00a9\U00c4 \U2021\U00ae\U220f\U2021\U00a9\U00e0\U2021\U00ae\U2260\U2021\U00a9\U221e \U2021\U00ae\U00f3\U2021\U00a9\U00c5\U2021\U00ae\U221e \U2021\U00ae\U2122\U2021\U00a9\U00e7\U2021\U00ae\U221e\U2021\U00ae\U220f\U2021\U00ae\U00e6\U2021\U00ae\U00b6\U2021\U00ae\U00f8 \U2021\U2022\U2022";
        pageNumber = 1;
    },
```

Here is the DB code from where I am getting data:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) tableBani:(NSString *)_query
{
    NSMutableArray *drr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *query;
    query =_query;

    const char *sql = [query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(dataBaseConnection,sql, -1, &statement, NULL)!= SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSAssert1(0,@"error preparing statement",sqlite3_errmsg(dataBaseConnection));
    }
    else
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            [drr addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:

                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)],@"ID",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)],@"pageNumber",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,2)],@"PunjabiText",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,3)],@"HindiText",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,4)],@"EnglishText",
                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,5)],@"EnglishTranslation",


                            nil]];

        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    return drr;
}
```

I don't know how can I get text in Punjabi or Hindi format. Please suggest me how to get actual text from database. I have also tried to convert text in utf-8 but no result. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please show me how you display this text?

Comment: I am using this :    NSData *dataenc = [string dataUsingEncoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *encodevalue = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataenc encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"result string: %@", encodevalue);
    self.textView.text = encodevalue;

Comment: If I decode the string then get null

Comment: @Muhammad this is giving me an error.

Comment: Can you add "tableBani" method in above question? May be issue is with fetching data from db.

Comment: Show the code that actually writes and reads the data from/to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

Just try below code once:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char*)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];
```

Hope it will work. :)

Comment: Its crash my application.

Comment: convertedString: ‡©¥ ‡®∏‡®§‡®ø ‡®®‡®æ‡®Æ‡©Å ‡®ï‡®∞‡®§‡®æ ‡®™‡©Å‡®∞‡®ñ‡©Å ‡®®‡®ø‡®∞‡®≠‡®â ‡®®‡®ø‡®∞‡®µ‡©à‡®∞‡©Å ‡®Ö‡®ï‡®æ‡®≤ ‡®Æ‡©Ç‡®∞‡®§‡®ø ‡®Ö‡®ú‡©Ç‡®®‡©Ä ‡®∏‡©à‡®≠‡©∞ ‡®ó‡©Å‡®∞ ‡®™‡©ç‡®∞‡®∏‡®æ‡®¶‡®ø ‡••   (lldb)

Comment: what does 3 stand for? isnt'it supposed to be 0 instead of 3 ?